# trying to use a recycled bitmap

Tags: android

i dont know how to solve this type of exception..
please help me...

```
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@41214638
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1026)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1127)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:393)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:979)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2437)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3763)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2183)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2258)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2153)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2021)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1832)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-23 12:36:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(2033):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 12:36:04.505: I/Process(2033): Sending signal. PID: 2033 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It's called `RuntimeException`. Technically, you should not manipulate a recycled bitmap to avoid this error. You should make use of `bitmap.isRecycled()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use recycled bitmaps.  If you need to check, use the isRecycled function before using a bitmap that might be and avoid using it if it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

If your bitmap is used on the screen don't call `bitmap.recycle()`. If you call this it will lead to the exception

Comment: its work.. error solved...